# Can't load index page

Tags: express, swig-template

I am trying to load my index page, I am using Swig template engine and Express. I get this error:

```
{
  "message": "Failed to lookup view \"/front/index\" in views directory \"/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/server/views\"",
  "error": {
    "view": {
      "defaultEngine": "html",
      "ext": ".html",
      "name": "/front/index",
      "root": "/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/server/views"
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't make sense unless I am missing something because the file path is this:

`/asset-management/server/views/front/index.html`

the `/views/front/index.html` should be correct based off the error right? What am I missing here? I can get other files to work in directories other than front. I have tried copying the part of the path needed into my route.

Route:

```
// homepage and dashboard
  app.get('/',
    setRedirect({auth: '/dashboard'}),
    isUnauthenticated,
    setRender('/front/index'),
    main.getHome);
```

Ignore the most of the middleware and look at the `setRender` as that is what is equivalent to `res.render()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an extra slash that shouldn't be there.

This:

```
setRender('/front/index'),
```

should be this:

```
setRender('front/index'),
```